# What is the error in this batch code?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

```
SET /p con1=----Do you want to display some text?(y/n):
IF con1==y (echo hi)
```

But this is not displaying "hi" on the command prompt screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
SET "con1=n"
SET /p "con1=----Do you want to display some text (y/n)? "
SET "con1=%con1:"=%"
IF /I "%con1%"=="y" (echo hi)
```

You forgot the percent signs to reference the value of variable `con1`. Therefore your IF compared fixed string `con1` with fixed string `y` which are never equal.

The compare is now not case-sensitive because of parameter `/I`.

A default value is set in case of user just hits enter on prompt.

And last double quotes are removed from entered value in case of user enters one or more `"` instead of just `y` or `n` as otherwise the batch execution would break on line with IF condition because of a syntax error.